# eclipse rcp perspectiveExtension showInPart not visible

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want my ViewPart add to `Show In` group. I added `perspectiveExtension` and add `showInPart` under it, when I run/debug my plugin, my view not appears in `Show In` context menu group.

Here is my extension point in `plugin.xml`

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <showInPart
           id="com.ex.views.DebugView">
     </showInPart>
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective">
     <showInPart
           id="com.ex.views.DebugView">
     </showInPart>
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

Comment: Does your view implement `IShowInTarget`? You are trying this in the Java or Resource perspective (not the Plugin Development perspective for example)? You may need to reset the perspective.

Comment: Yes, 
1. The DebugView implements IShowInTarget
2. I tried the Java or Resource perspective in debugged target eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse 4.15 (though likely also any 4.x), I had to start in a new workspace for such changes to have an effect. When debugging Eclipse (in a non-clean/old workspace), the changes had no effect.